# When are EventGrid IoT Hub DeviceConnected and DeviceDisconnected Events raised

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventgrid

IoT Hub publishes the events "DeviceConnected" and "DeviceDisconnected" via Event Grid [according to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-event-grid#event-types).

My question is, which action from an actual IoT Device triggers these events?

For the "DeviceConnected" event:

- Is it triggered when the OpenAsync Method is called on the Client SDK?
- Is it triggered implicitly when the SendEvent Method is called?
- Is this event also available via direct AMQP/MQTT connections?
- For how long will it stay in this state?

For the "DeviceDisconnected" event:

- Is the device going to "disconnected" as soon as "Close" on the DeviceClient is called?
- What if connectivity is not good? Is there a constant ping along with a timeout mechanism which marks a device as offline after it was idle for a given time?

We currently have implemented the heartbeat pattern as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-identity-registry#device-heartbeat) but we are wondering if there is an easier and eventually more cost-efficient way to achieve the same goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this passage in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-identity-registry#device-heartbeat)

> The connection state is updated only for devices using MQTT or AMQP.
> Also, it is based on protocol-level pings (MQTT pings, or AMQP pings),
> and it can have a maximum delay of only 5 minutes. For these reasons,
> there can be false positives, such as devices reported as connected
> but that are disconnected.

This covers most of my questions.

Comment: I think this is the `connectionState` property, and not the event(s).